# Help me find my mistake when finding the exact value of the infinite sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{n-2}}{5^{n-1}}$

Tags: summation, geometric-series

> Finding the exact value of the infinite sum:
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{n-2}}{5^{n-1}}$$

**My Approach:**

First term (**a**);

$$\frac{e^{-2}}{5^{-1}}=\frac{5}{e^2}$$

Second term:

$$\frac{e^{-1}}{5^{0}}=\frac{1}{e}$$

The difference (**r**):

$$r=\frac{e}{5}$$

Applying the geometric sum formula:

$$\frac{\frac{5}{e^2}}{1-\frac{e}{5}}=\frac{\frac{5}{e^2}}{\frac{5-e}{5}}$$

$$=\frac{25}{e^2(5-e)}$$

**Unfortunately this is wrong, where have I gone wrong in this?**

Comment: I think your sum is correct. Wolframalpha gives the same answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7Bn-2%7D%7D%7B5%5E%7Bn-1%7D%7D

Comment: It's correct...

Comment: @thanasissdr Thanks!

Comment: @Nicholas Oh Thanks

Comment: It's right. Minor correction in terminology: should say "ratio" rather than "difference" (terms are members of a geometric sequence, not an arithmetic sequence). Except for that, your analysis is flawless! +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum is correct.

One may recall a standard result concerning geometric series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac{r}{1-r},\qquad |r|<1.
$$ Applying it with $r=\dfrac{e}5\,\,\left(\left|\dfrac{e}5\right|<1\right)$, gives

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{n-2}}{5^{n-1}}=\frac{e^{-2}}{5^{-1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{n}}{5^{n}}=\frac{e^{-2}}{5^{-1}}\frac1{1-e/5}=\frac{25}{e^2(5-e)}
> $$

as you have found.